# subprocess.check_output() fails silently

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

So I wrote this script that does a lot of different things, one of which is executing shell commands. the program runs fine and as intended until I run it with the console hidden (pythonw.exe). this is the line that fails

```
result = subprocess.check_output(" & ".join(CMD[0] + CMD[1]), shell=True)
```

I have seen similar problems with the subprocess module on here but none with this function and they all had an error to work with.. this dose not error or do its thing so I have no idea whats going on.

is there a way to fix this that still lets me run multiple commands at the same time?

EDIT:

the variable CMD will always be something like this

```
[["cd C:\Users\John\Desktop","cd Random","cd Folder"],["dir"]]
```

again the code is not wrong, it works fine when it is executed as a .py file, it is only when it is executed as .pyw (which hides the console) that it stops working, but there is no error, I checked with try/catch.

Comment: Have you checked what `" & ".join(CMD[0] + CMD[1])` is equal to? Is not what you think it is.

Comment: my code works fine, it only stops working when it is run as a .pyw file

Comment: please provide [MCVE]. What is the simplest value for `CMD` that exposes your issue? What error are you getting? Make it reproducible for us.